# How to declare a deep nested resource in activeadmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, rails-routing, nested-routes

I have three resources in ActiveAdmin i.e User, Order, and OrderItems.

```
User => has_many :orders

User => has_many :order_items, through: :orders
```

I want OrderItems to be nested inside Users so I can have these routes:

> ```
> admin/users/:user_id/orders/:order_id/order_items
> admin/users/:user_id/orders/:order_id/order_items/:id
> admin/users/:user_id/orders/:order_id/order_items/:id/new
> admin/users/:user_id/orders/:order_id/order_items/:id/edit
> ```

I tried with the below code but it is not working.

```
ActiveAdmin.register OrderItems do 

  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :user
  controller do
    nested_belongs_to  :user, :order
    end
  end
end
```

How can I achieve this with activeadmin?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean "not working" what does `rake routes` show? [Have you seen this?](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/376#issuecomment-4070071)

Comment: @engineersmnky  `rake routes` results as below.                         
`admin/users/:user_id/order_items
admin/users/:user_id/order_items/:id
admin/users/:user_id/order_items/:id/new
admin/users/:user_id/order_items/:id/edit`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `routes.rb` file

```
 namespace :admin do
    resources :users do
      resources :orders do
         resources :order_items
      end
    end
  end
```

However I do not think it is proper to nest up to this level

Comment: I know it is not good to have such a deep nested route. But the client wants it that way itself. I tried with the one have suggested but after code review, ppl rejected the code telling that it should be handled in the active admin resource itself. @chrisgeeq